# VCard import with umlauts are not working in Outlook with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, outlook, vcf-vcard

I wrote a Plugin which generates a VCF-File in the Windows storage. If i save it in **UTF-8**, *Windows People* will be able to read correctly all Umlauts.
If i import the vcf-file in *Outlook* every Ü is an Ã¼.

If i save the VCF-File in **ISO-8859-1** in *Outlook*, i can read the umlauts but 
then Windows People get the Black Questionmark for the umlauts.

How can i fix the encoding Problem? Is there a standard for all Platforms?

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please read the following post before posting a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post the same VCF fiel that causes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put the Version to 2.1 and set the CHARSET to UTF-8 fixed the problem!

```
 vcard.AppendLine("VERSION:2.1");
 vcard.AppendFormat("N;CHARSET=utf-8:{0};{1};{2};{3}\r\n", 
 json.lastName,json.firstName, json.middleName,json.title);
```